# Fitch Proof and Logic prove A V D given premises 1. A V B 2. ¬C ∨ ¬B

Tags: logic

I have to prove this in Fitch without using any of the cons

Comment: We do not do HW for people. Present your own attempt and we can help correct mistakes, if any.

Comment: There is a good reason you are having trouble.  (A ∨ D) is **not** logically entailed by (A V B) and (¬C ∨ ¬B).  Is there something missing or miscopied?

Comment: I think the question is not off-topic, but I'm not saying I understand it. Where does the statement D come from? Is it random? "A or D" is true in the sense that once you say A is true, then "A or [anything]" is true.

Comment: @MarkAndrews That is why the question is off topic.  It is missing the details needed to answer it.

Comment: @GrahamKemp In general, I think logic questions are on topic. If the question is missing pieces to the puzzle, I see that as a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a [generated truth table](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) for the statement "((A or B)&&(~C or ~B))=>(A or D)".

Note the line where the result is False (F).

[image]

---

Stanford Truth Table Tool, http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/

Comment: Is the implication the primary connective in this truth table? The implication seems to be the main connective in what is written and --NOT the disjunction. The way you wrote this it appears you are focusing on the disjunction.  The row looks correct on if the implication was used just weird the way you aligned the table.

Comment: Yes, it is the implication that is the main connective: the conjunction of the two premises *imply* the disjunction "A v D". The table is a screenshot of the output of the truth table tool. I did nothing more than enter the formula into the tool.